# Math.Log and round number

Tags: c#, math, rounding

```
var result = Math.Log(1000, 10);
var diff = result - 3;
```

`diff` is about `-4x10^-16`.

As I understood it, the exact value 3 could be stored in a double:

```
3 (base 10) = 1.1x10^1 (base 2)
```

Am I wrong or does it mean that Math.Log is not exact, at least for value 1000?

Comment: floating point numbers are not exact

Comment: @Matt As far as I understood, the value 3 could be stored exactly in a floating point number (see the value 3 in base 2 in my post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `Math.Log10` in this case

```
var result1 = Math.Log(1000, 10); //result1: 2.9999999999999996
var result2 = Math.Log10(1000);  //result2: 3
```